# What does this async function do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework, async-await

I'm new to async/await in JS. This is an ionic react app I'm looking at and I'm not sure what it does. Can someone explain it to me like I'm 5?

```
const handleClick = async(e, operator) => {
        if(operator == "MC"){
            if(isPlatform("android")){
                 await Storage.remove({key:'history'})

            }else{
                window.localStorage.removeItem("history")
            }
            return false
        }else if(operator == "MR"){
            let storage = ""
            let parse = ""
            if(isPlatform("android")){
                let storage = await Storage.get({key:'history'})
                 parse = JSON.parse(storage.value)
            }else{
                let storage = await window.localStorage.getItem("history")
                parse = JSON.parse(storage)
            }
            setSumHistory(parse[0].expration)
            return false
            
        }}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @robertklep what does await do at lines 4,14, and 17?

Comment: @HectorFunes Have you tried taking it out? Do you know what `Storage.remove()` and `Storage.get()` return? Do you know what `await` does in general?

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await

Comment: (Tbh it does nothing useful in line 17, [`localStorage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) does not return a promse)

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for clarification for async/await I will cover that part.

If you add async to a function this means that the function will always return a promise. https://javascript.info/async-await

The `handleClick` function will wait on the following lines for a promise to resolve or reject.

```
await Storage.remove({key:'history'})
....
let storage = await Storage.get({key:'history'})
....
let storage = await window.localStorage.getItem("history")
```

If one of these calls gets rejected handleClick with throw an error since there is no try / catch block around these await calls.
https://javascript.info/try-catch

Hope this will help you get a better understanding of async await in this code block.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a line that needs time to be resolved and the next line depends on on the results of that line of code, you need to **await** that line to complete by returning a **promise**.
and to tell the function there is a line you need to resolve that will return a promise you need to add **async** to that function.